# Need to state "$p$ not equal to $61$" when solving $61p + 1 = n^2$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

In the pictures below, am I wrong to say that the 3 lines in the red box are not needed in the solutions? Regardless of whether 61 and p are distinct, it's still true that we have only the 2 possible cases, isn't it?

And the 2 cases would eliminate p = 61 anyway, even if I don't see that p cannot be 61.

[image]

[image]

Comment: $(+1)$ for your fine effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The prime factorization of $(n+1)(n-1)$ is given by $61p$.  So long as each of $n+1, n-1$ contains at least one prime divisor, then one of them must be $61$, the other must be $p$.  No need to care if $p=61$ or not.

However, you do need to worry about if $n-1=1$, which has no prime dividing it.  Luckily this case is easy to dispose of, since $61$ does not divide $(2+1)(2-1)=3$.

Answer (score 0):

Perfectly fine. Line $7$ is probably *Superfluous*(Not sure of that).

Another way: You can instead consider $(\mod 4)$ at first, you can just eliminate all the $1(\mod 4)$ numbers from the naturals.